# Ordering the queryset fields

Tags: json, django

I'm currently fetching  values from a queryset and serializing it into json below:
`JsonResponse( list( Company.objects.defer('id').all().values() ), safe = False )`

so if the `company` has the following fields: `Name`, `Description`, `Employees`
How can I control the ordering of the fields. If i say `order_by('Name')` then my results will be sorted according to names.

Instead, I want to specify it as `Description`, `Name`, `Employees` and get my answer in that same order.

Comment: Well you can do `Company.objects.all().order_by('description', 'name', 'employees')`.

Comment: I tried Company.objects.all().values().order_by('name', 'description')
but it still gives it to me in the order of description, name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll assume that employees is a foreign key in the model company and you need to order them by 'description', 'name', 'employees name'.

It should be like this:

```
Company.objects.all().order_by('description', 'name', 'employees__name')
```

If you specify make like this:

```
Company.objects.all().order_by('description', 'name', 'employees')
```

It will sort by description, name and employees references which actually will not give the order you want.

**Edit 1** If employees are character field you can do also the following

```
class Company(models.Model):
    .....
    class Meta:
       ordering = ['description', 'name', 'employees']
```

Comment: No employee is not a foreign key, but I can see why you thought that, because I said order_by(names) in the question, I have changed that now. So here description, name and employees are all charFields

Comment: what would I do if it was a DateField or IntegerField?

Comment: It should not be different. I think it will be different if there is a foreign key without override `__str__` function. But always you can give it a try.

Comment: can you try removing `.all()` and make it `Company.objects.order_by('description', 'name', 'employees')`

Comment: still no luck with it

Comment: can you post a sample of the sorting?

Comment: {u'description': u'Magnifly is making the world a better place by developing secure AES-encrypted SaaS platforms for users to exchange and store personal and private data.', u'series': u'Series F', u'founded': u'2002-08-02', u'valuation': 2910000000.0, u'id': 6, u'name': u'Magnifly'},

I specified order by name, description, ..... and the order does not budge even with the meta class

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102406/discussion-between-ahmed-hosny-and-ash).